# unable to apply for an array of <a> link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following markup inside my third part application

```
<a href="/Lists/NewsAnnouncements/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2FLists%2FNewsAnnouncements;FolderCTID=0x01200200881E90B7B49B8345B5DEB72152BE6494&amp;
View=%7BFF37C57C%2D57F1%2D4B05%2DBF9C%2D00A88004E54A%7D">
<span class="ms-textLarge ms-noWrap">item A</span></a>

<a href="/Lists/NewsAnnouncements/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2FLists%2FNewsAnnouncements;FolderCTID=0x01200200881E90B7B49B8345B5DEB72152BE6494&amp;
View=%7BFF37C57C%2D57F1%2D4B05%2DBF9C%2D00A88004E54A%7D">
<span class="ms-textLarge ms-noWrap">testing</span></a>
```

now i want to add `'target', '_blank'` attribute to my links, so they get opened in a new tabs. so i tried the following script:-

```
<script src="/sites/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>

var els = $('a:contains("NewsAnnouncements")');

for(var i = 0, l = els.length; i < l; i++) {

  el.attr('target', '_blank');
}

</script>
```

but nothing were added to the links, alo the console did not raise any issues. so i am not sure what is wrong with my code?

Comment: i don't see you declaring `el` at any point. You have `els` though. Also what's the point of the `for` loop if you're not doing anything with the `i`

Answer (score 1):

Value is in `href` attribute, not in the text so use *attribute-contains* `*` selector

```
var els = $('a[href*="NewsAnnouncements"]');

for(var i = 0, l = els.length; i < l; i++) {

  $(els[i]).attr('target', '_blank');
}
```

Or simply

```
$('a[href*="NewsAnnouncements"]').each( function(){
  $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$('a[href*="NewsAnnouncements"]').each(function() {
  $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="/Lists/NewsAnnouncements/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2FLists%2FNewsAnnouncements;FolderCTID=0x01200200881E90B7B49B8345B5DEB72152BE6494&amp;
View=%7BFF37C57C%2D57F1%2D4B05%2DBF9C%2D00A88004E54A%7D">
  <span class="ms-textLarge ms-noWrap">item A</span></a>

<a href="/Lists/NewsAnnouncements/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2FLists%2FNewsAnnouncements;FolderCTID=0x01200200881E90B7B49B8345B5DEB72152BE6494&amp;
View=%7BFF37C57C%2D57F1%2D4B05%2DBF9C%2D00A88004E54A%7D">
  <span class="ms-textLarge ms-noWrap">testing</span></a>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.. now i added `alert(els.length);` and seems it will be 1 ,, so the selector has only selected one link, while i have around 20..

Comment: @johnG In the demo I have shared, it is able to set attribute to all links. Please check

Comment: No need to iterate over all the elements `$('a[href*="NewsAnnouncements"]');`

Comment: @YosvelQuintero You are right, but you have already answered that. So, I don't want to add the same in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `each()` on each `els` element and add the attribute `target = '_blank'` accordingly:

```
var els = $('a[href*="NewsAnnouncements"]');

els.each(function(){
 $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

Here is the working snippet. To check the correctness of the code use the browser's `inspect element` on the link and check that the attribute has been added.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var els = $('a[href*="NewsAnnouncements"]');

  els.each(function(){
   $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="/Lists/NewsAnnouncements/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2FLists%2FNewsAnnouncements;FolderCTID=0x01200200881E90B7B49B8345B5DEB72152BE6494&amp;
View=%7BFF37C57C%2D57F1%2D4B05%2DBF9C%2D00A88004E54A%7D">
<span class="ms-textLarge ms-noWrap">item A</span></a>

<a href="/Lists/NewsAnnouncements/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2FLists%2FNewsAnnouncements;FolderCTID=0x01200200881E90B7B49B8345B5DEB72152BE6494&amp;
View=%7BFF37C57C%2D57F1%2D4B05%2DBF9C%2D00A88004E54A%7D">
<span class="ms-textLarge ms-noWrap">testing</span></a>
```

Comment: now i added `alert(els.length);` and seems it will be 1 ,, so the selector has only selected one link, while i have around 20..

Comment: No need to iterate over all the elements `$('a[href*="NewsAnnouncements"]');`

Answer (score 0):

No need to iterate over the elements `$('a[href*="NewsAnnouncements"]');`

**jQuery [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) Get the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of matched elements or set one or more attributes for every matched element.**

Than, you can simply do:

```
$('a[href*="NewsAnnouncements"]').attr('target', '_blank');
```